# How would you check if a specific filename exists in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-storage

Please note my question is different from other similar questions because it's specifically about using Google Cloud Storage with c++ instead of other languages supported in AppEngine.

How could you elegantly check if a filename exists in Google Cloud Storage via curl or by any other means (C++)?
Currently, when requesting a file that doesn't exist it's returning with `file not found` which is indistinguishable from a file that contains this string as it's content. It would be cool to be able to check if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object exists, you should issue a `HEAD` request to the object URL. You might be seeing `file not found` in the *body* of the response, but you should check the response *code* for the value `404`. An object that exists will return `200`.

You can see an example `HEAD` request/response at the [HEAD Object reference page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#headobject)

Comment: Thanks for the link but there are no examples there. It is hard to get some test code running. :) I mean there are examples but they aren't generic, they rely on their API and my code needs to be in C++, probably with libcur for communication.

Comment: Did you end up finding some examples for C++ authentication using libcurl for google cloud?